# Purpose of these resistors in the input of in-amp

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

there is an instrumentation-amp here.

there is two electrodes which in primary sensor get uv to a few mv ac induced voltage.

and also impedance of the primary sensor is too high and as i know reason of using an in-amp is having a low input bios current (high input impedance in the range of   Gohm) in order to deal high impedance of sensor.

so it seems odd to my why in this example circuit, there is two 270k resistor to the ground? do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: AC coupled, you need a path for the bias current.

Comment: doesn't it impact input impedance?

Comment: Are you assuming the designer knew they were attenuating the  electrode? with 270k  .  Perhaps the impedance of the event changes to a lower value.

Comment: i know that impedance of the electrodes is high ,so as George Herold said i need a path for the bias current  .  isn't there any way to have a high input impedance in the first stage?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a path for the input bias current.

If you want higher input impedance you can use an in-amp with lower input bias current (and higher resistors) or you can live with more offset voltage or use a bootstrapped arrangement. Or use lower gain and AC couple the first stage to another stage.

In some cases you may be able to DC-couple the input stage.

There are lots of possibilities, you need to define the requirements for **differential** and **common-mode** input impedance.

Comment: why i need a path for the input bias current? in other word what happens if i remove  R6 and R7?

Comment: The input bias currents will cause the voltages at the inputs to charge the capacitors and the in-amp will saturate, either from differential input or because you have exceeded the input common mode range. If 10nA is coming out of an input, then the input voltage will increase by 10mV/second as the 1uF capacitor charges.

Comment: i need to reject common-mode and amplify differential-mode  of electrodes. so for this requirements what arrangement is suitable?

Comment: Requirements have *numbers* associated with them.

Comment: yes you are right i will be back with more details.before that can you please give me any link or example about bootstrapped arrangement? i confused what  is a bootstrapped arrangement here?

Comment: as you said "In some cases you may be able to DC-couple the input stage." what exactly makes me able to do that?

Comment: @alireza, what's the impedance to which the electrodes are attached?  And is it somehow ground referenced.  (not floating at 100V or something.)  There are instrument amps with smallish bias current.  I used the ina121 in my last project.  You may be able to remove the DC blocking caps.  Or even use something like the ina121 with larger resistors... 10 or 100 Meg ohms.

Comment: since you had experience with ina121 i would be grateful if you tell me if i can use ina121 with a single supply +5v , reference pin and virtual ground tied to 2v , input Vcm range 1v to 3v , ac coupled input with 1mohm Ib return path, and acceptable output swing (for example 0.4 v to 4.6 v)?

Comment: I don't think so. See the graph on page 4 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina121.pdf), bottom-most right.